# Is it possible to retrain a trained model on fewer classes?

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection

I am working on image detection where I am detecting and classifying an image into one of 14 different thoric diseases (multi-label classification problem).
The model is trained on `NIH dataset` with which I get `80% AUC`. Now I want to improve the model by training on a second dataset. But the main problem is both dataset's classes are not matched.

The second dataset contains 10 classes that overlap with the first dataset with which I trained the model.

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to retrain a model on fewer classes.
2. Will retraining my model on a new dataset impact the AUC of other non-similar classes?
3. How big is the chance that this will improve the model?

The model and code are based on `fast.ai` and `PyTorch`.

Comment: If you want to train a new classifier for the new dataset, then you can try that keeping the feature extractor frozen and training a 10-class classifier. If you want a single classifier for both datasets, training alternately with both datasets might be better. Because training only on new dataset may lead to information loss about other classes.

Comment: Do you want to use the dataset with 10 classes as additional training data? Are the 10 classes of the one dataset also part of 14 classes of the other dataset? You can definitely make a pipeline that trains on one dataset, reinitializes the classifier and continues training on the other dataset. Or alternating, as suggested. Whether its an improvement is dependent on my question about the datasets.

Comment: Thanks, @akshayk07  my project is divided into two modules with two different models:
1- Classification module
2- Detection module
I know I will train first the classification model and then load those weights to continue training the detection module.
Just I am confused that whether if I reduce the number of classes the other classes AUC will affect or not?
I can't train a single model for each class as this problem is a multi-label class- and detection problem so I am thinking to prepare a combined dataset.
Does it will be worthy?

Comment: @Kroshtan yes I want to retrain the trained model on the new dataset to improve AUC.
No, it is not a part of 14 classes dataset but it's a different dataset Dataset Name: [NIH](https://www.kaggle.com/nih-chest-xrays/data) and [VinBig](https://www.kaggle.com/c/vinbigdata-chest-xray-abnormalities-detection/data).
But there are 10 classes are similar so that why I want to train on that dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Based on discussion in the comments:

1. Yes, if the classes overlap (with different data points from a different dataset) you can train the same classifier layer with two datasets. This would mean in one of the datasets, 4 out of 14 classes are simply not trained. What this means is that you are basically making your existing 14-class dataset more imbalanced by adding more samples for only 10 out of 14 classes.
2. Training on 10 out of 14 classes will introduce a forgetting effect on the 4 classes that are not trained additionally. You can counteract this somewhat by using the suggested alternate training, or by combining all the data into one big dataset, but this does not solve the fact that the new combined dataset is then probably more imbalanced than the original 14-class dataset. Unless the 4 classes not in the 10-class dataset are for some reason over represented in the 14-class dataset, but I assume you're not going to get that lucky.
3. Because both your dataset and your model will focus heavier on 10 out of the 14 classes, your accuracy may go up. However, this means that the 4 classes that do not overlap are simply being ignored in favor of higher accuracy on the remaining 10 classes. On paper, the numbers may look better, but in practice you're making your model less useful for a 14-class classification task.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed suggestion.

Replying answer:
1- But here the data is not that much low that it creates imbalance issues. LIke Dataset 1: `112120 images` and Dataset 2: `14k+ images`.
2- What do you mean by the forgetting effect? like it will not recognize those classes where it does not train again in 2nd training?
3- In practice what if we delete those non-matched classes and then trained that model on 10 classes and retrain on the 2nd dataset?

Comment: 1. That would definitely reduce imbalance, but also might not add too much if you're only adding a relatively small amount of images. 2. I mean that if you train on a new task with just 10 classes, any connections trained to detect the other 4 classes will weaken and accuracy for those classes will drop (be forgotten). 3. Then you just have a bigger dataset for a 10-class problem, which is great, but then you only are able to detect 10 classes, which is not so great.

Comment: agree with points 1, 2. I am reviewing my idea with my supervisor and it's okay I know it will only classify and detect 10 classes for now.
I will accept the answer once if some other experts gave an answer too.
Thanks for your quick response.